# Unresolved reference GestureDetector for swipe events

Tags: android

Can someone please point me in the right direction to resolving this.

GestureDector is suddenly appearing as an 'unresolved reference'. It has correctly imported in the past and  no longer works. (see image below).

I have tried invalidating caches, and have confirmed its also unavailable in new projects. I dont believe there are any special dependencies I've missed and its not deprecated.

Has something has happend to the class file? if so, whats the easiest way to replace or update it?

Any suggestions welcome. Thanks

[image]

Comment: did Gradle sync complete ?

Comment: @Noah Yes, sync completes without issue.